# index.html in github repo not opening

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to see a static html file. My github url is [anuragasaurus.github.io](https://anuragasaurus.github.io) and my repo name is [js-playground](https://github.com/anuragasaurus/js-playground), it contains a `index.html` file.
I am trying to open [anuragasaurus.github.io/js-playground/index.html](https://anuragasaurus.github.io/js-playground/index.html) but it's showing 404.

Can anybody tell me how can I access `index.html` file in my `js-playground` repo.

Comment: You must create a brach called `hg-pages` and place your index.html there. read [this](https://pages.github.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to view your project files as static webpage, you should store your files not in default `master` branch but in `gh-pages` branch.
You can create this branch using multiple methods but in order to find out the convenient one, you can use this [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) link.

Basically, let's assume that you already have `master` branch. If you are using `git` command line tool, you can do that with these steps:

1. `cd your-project-folder`
2. `git checkout -b gh-pages` (it will create new branch and switch to it)
3. `git push origin gh-pages` (it will create new branch on GitHub repo and push the existing files to it)